# Does the following code invoke UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Does the following code invoke UB ?

```
int main(){
  volatile int i = 0;
  volatile int* p = &i;
  int j = ++i * *p;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is **Undefined Behavior** because you are trying to violate the second rule..

> The Standard states that
>
> 1) Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>
> 2) **Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored**.

*Note*: The order of evaluation of the operands of `*` operator is **unspecified** and `*p` is nothing but `i`.

Comment: @Prasoon : It is not right to edit others' posts just to format their code with your favorite style of indentation. Haven't you read the StackOverflow guidelines - "Respect the original author" ? (>_<)

Answer (score 9):

Yes - either ++i or *p (which is i) can be evaluated first.

Comment: but regardless of order of evaluation the result would be same right?

Comment: No. If ++i is evaluated first, you have 1 * 1. If *p is evaluated first, you have 1 * 0.

Comment: Oops! How could I not notice that! 

Thanks for the response!

Comment: Remember that this isn't just unspecified, it's undefined.  It will almost certainly return 0 or 1 on all systems I'm familiar with, and keep on going, but that isn't a language guarantee.

Comment: @David Yes indeed. I should have pointed that out in my answer.